# invalid type (list) message in applying gmm method

Tags: r, gmm

The moment condition function is simply exp(-g/r)-1, where g is a known series of daily return on AAA-class bond index, and r is the rikiness measure to be derived through gmm. My codes are as follows:

```
View(Source)
library(gmm)
data(Source)
x <- Source[1:5200,"AAA"]
m <- function(r,x)
 {m.1 <- exp(-x[,"AAA"]/r)-1}
summary(gmm(m,x,t0=1,method="BFGS",control=1e-12))
```

Which in term yields the following error message:

> ****Error in model.frame.default(formula = gmat ~ 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     invalid type (list) for variable 'gmat'****

Could anyone help me figure out what went wrong?
Thanks a lot!

For those kind people who would like to replicate the results, please find attached the source data as mentioned above.
The correct r is 1.590 , which can be solved through goal searching in excel, with target function :(average(exp(-g/r)-1) )^2 and target value: 0 (tolerance: 1e-12)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AnTErQd2jm9ttKDZa7On3DLzEZUWaz5Km3nKaB7K18o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try to add some data so your question is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please. [ maybe try so function `m` returns something ie  either remove `m.1<-` , or add `{m.1<- exp(-x[,"AAA"]/r)-1 ; return(m.1)}`

Comment: @user20650  `\`<-\` ` _does_ return something. the return of function `m` should be a matrix, however, and it sounds like you are getting a data frame